# Get browser version & operating system version of client after order is placed

Tags: magento-1.9

Can any body suggest me a module in magento 1.9 which can help me to detect client's **browser version** & **operating system** version of client after order is placed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dont know about ready made module but you can achieve this functionality via observer  `sales_order_place_after` with this event you can get save user and order data in your module or saving in magento order module by rewriting that module

You can get user operating system and other detail in `$_SERVER` you will get user agent detail via this `$_SERVER ['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];` variable

I think you are able to create rest of the thing

Comment: Why e-Commerce sites care so much about such information, I understand the need prior to HTML5 but after that what is the use?

Comment: @NoChance: If a customer has problems with their order and you would like to reproduce this problem, you can try and use the same browser and operation system as the customer did. This is why some sites want this.

Comment: @JelleSiderius, makes lot of sense. Thanks.